# shortening the SUMIFS formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, sumifs

Helo, can help me. Is there a way to shorten the formula I provided?
=IFERROR(SUMIFS('Sheet1'!$C:$C,'Sheet1'!$B:$B,$A4,'Sheet1'!$D:$D,$F$3,'Sheet1'!$E:$E,**$M$1**,'Sheet1'!$A:$A,$I$3)+SUMIFS('Sheet1'!$C:$C,'Sheet1'!$B:$B,$A4,'Sheet1'!$D:$D,$F$3,'Sheet1'!$E:$E,**$M$2**,'Sheet1'!$A:$A,$I$3)+SUMIFS('Sheet1'!$C:$C,'Sheet1'!$B:$B,$A4,'Sheet1'!$D:$D,$F$3,'Sheet1'!$E:$E,**$M$3**,'Sheet1'!$A:$A,$I$3))

because I calculated many conditions from the $M$1;$M$2;$M$3 value

I want to get a simple formula

Comment: Not tested: =SUM(Sheet1!$C:$C*N(Sheet1!$B:$B=$A4)*N(Sheet1!$D:$D=$F$3)*N(Sheet1!$E:$E=$M$1+Sheet1!$E:$E=$M$2+Sheet1!$E:$E=$M$3)*N(Sheet1!$A:$A=$I$3))

Comment: Sorry what the *N  ?

Comment: It is not *N, it is N() - converts TRUE/FALSE to 1/0, but not necessary in sheets in this case. Also corrected formula: =ARRAYFORMULA(sum(Sheet1!$C:$C*(Sheet1!$B:$B=$A4)*(Sheet1!$D:$D=$F$3)*((Sheet1!$E:$E=$M$1)+(Sheet1!$E:$E=$M$2)+(Sheet1!$E:$E=$M$3))*(Sheet1!$A:$A=$I$3)))

Comment: ok thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter()` and `match()`, like this:

```
=sum(ifna(filter( 
  Sheet1!C1:C, 
  match(Sheet1!E1:E, M1:M3, 0), 
  Sheet1!A1:A, = I3, Sheet1!B1:B = A4, Sheet1!D1:D = F3 
)))
```

See
[filter()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093197),
[ifna()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9365944)
and
[match()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378).

Comment: ok thanks for help.

Comment: See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)